# How to extract Hex colors from html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello i'm trying to extract hex colors from a html page converted to a string.

Given the following string:

```
"<div style="color: #00A9F8"></div><div style="color: #00000"></div>"
```

**How do you convert that into an array of hex codes like this using ruby?:**

```
["#00A9F8", #00000]
```

I've tried to use regex `^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$` but couldn't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains only one Hex code (`"#00A9F8"`). Other one has only 5 characters after `#`.

Anyways, you can fetch the required array with the help of [scan](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan):

```
str = '<div style="color: #00A9F8"></div><div style="color: #000000"></div>'

regex = /#[A-Z0-9]{6}/

str.scan(regex)
 => ["#00A9F8", "#000000"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is anchored. `^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end of a line, so your regex is only matching a string where the hex code is on a line by itself:

```
regex = /^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$/
snippet = %{
  <div style="color: #00A9F8"></div><div style="color: #000000"></div>
  <div style="color: \n#00A9F8\n"></div><div style="color: \n#000000\n"></div>
}

p snippet.scan(regex) # => ["#00A9F8", "#000000"] (i.e., only the last 2)
```

So, all you want need to change is remove the anchor, so it can match anywhere in the string:

```
regex = /#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}/
p snippet.scan(regex) # => ["#00A9F8", "#000000", "#00A9F8", "#000000"]
```